# Using the autogenerated Ui for both sender and receiver with qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer

I need to call a method after the ui has been shown,so i want to connect
the frame with itself,in particular using the show signal.
I've created a new form with auto generated code by qtcreator.This is the auto generated header.

```
#define STARTWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class StartWindow;
}

class StartWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit StartWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~StartWindow();

private:
Ui::StartWindow *ui;

public slots:
void doSomething();
};

#endif // STARTWINDOW_H
```

in the cpp file no one of the following codes work

```
connect(ui,SIGNAL(QEvent::Show),this,SLOT(doSomething()));

connect(*ui,SIGNAL(QEvent::Show),this,SLOT(doSomething()));

connect(this->ui,SIGNAL(QEvent::Show),this,SLOT(doSomething()));
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: `Ui::Foo` is a POD class and has neither the signals nor the slots. Its only use is to hold various widgets and layouts, and the initialization code. You want `connect(this, ..., this, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here:

1. There is no show() signal and
2. Even if there were, you aren't using connect correctly.

First, if your class were defined like this:

```
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void someSignal();

public slots:
    void doSomething() {}

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

The appropriate call to `connect` in the constructor would be:
`QWidget::connect(this, SIGNAL(someSignal()), this, SLOT(doSomething()));`

Even if there were a show signal, you wouldn't get it from `ui`, you would get it from `this`. The UI classes are just dumb containers for widgets that you add through the designer.

To perform some action when your class is shown, you can either override
 `virtual void showEvent(QShowEvent *);` (more robust, but slightly more complex)

or simply define your own show() slot that does what you want and calls QWidget::show() at the end of it. I prefer the latter, so I will show you that.

Start by defining your show slot like this:

```
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT 
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void doSomething() {}
    void show();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

Then, in your implementation file, do this:

```
void MainWindow::show()
{
    doSomething();
    QWidget::show();
}
```

I have worked with the Qt framework for quite some time now, and I have never needed to override the show event; it is simply not worth it for most use cases. If you really want a show signal that others can connect to, just add a custom signal for it and emit in in `MainWindow::show()`. Only resort to overriding event handlers if you can't make this work for what you are doing(*very* rarely necessary).

Answer (score 1):

That signal does not exist by default, we must create it, we can override the `showEvent()` method:

**.h**

```
protected:
    void showEvent(QShowEvent *event);

signals:
    void showSignal();
```

**.cpp**

```
 connect(this, &StartWindow::showSignal, this, &StartWindow::doSomething);

void StartWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
    emit showSignal();
    QMainWindow::showEvent(event);
}

void StartWindow::doSomething()
{
    qDebug()<<"show";
}
```

Or you can override the `eventFilter` method.

**.h**

```
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event);

signals:
    void showSignal();
```

**.cpp**

```
installEventFilter(this);

connect(this, &StartWindow::showSignal, this, &StartWindow::doSomething);

bool StartWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(watched==this && event->type() == QEvent::Show)
        emit showSignal();
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```

Comment: I've used the first method,the doSomething() method runs continuously ,the connect(....) string is in the constructor of the StartWindow ,so there are 2 problems: the first is that the signal is sent continuously and anyway is not sent when the form is shown but during the constructor.So even if i add a disconnect at the end doSomething the slot is called before the form is shown